# Combine multiple dynamic Leaflet filters

Tags: leaflet, geojson, filter

I'm very new to Leaflet and made a map using a GeoJSON Layer. I'd like to filter points from the GeoJSON Layer by a checkbox input. If I consider only one Parameter (Par1) with levels A, B and C I can do it: I  different subsets of my layer by pre-defining all possible filters:

```
function filterA(feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties.Par1 === "A") return true;
        };
```

The same I'd do for B and C, each resulting in a different Layer:

```
var dataA = L.geoJSON(oli_data.responseJSON, {
            pointToLayer: MakeMarker,
            filter: filterA,
            onEachFeature: MakePopUp
        }).addTo(map);
```

The same way I can create a subset for levels B and C using their filters. I let the user select the layer by:

```
            controler = L.control.layers(MapsTypes, {
            "A": dataA,
            "B": dataB
        }, {
            collapsed: true
        }).addTo(map);
```

Eventually I want to let the user filter the data by a combination of levels of Parameter1 and Parameter2. For that I would like to use Checkboxes, one with Parameter1 as title and all levels of Parameter1 as possible choices, and the same for Parameter2.

How can I achieve that without having to make extra layers for each possible combination of levels but rather by filtering by the actual user input?

Comment: I have an answer here that should sufficiently solve your problem too: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/308005/122597

Answer (score 0):

I have an example. To start I defined a GeoJSON layer by the "feature.properties.Verified" value being "N"  and the checkbox give a choice of either 'Y' or 'N'. I start with no, and if they check Y then it reloads the layer with a Yes filter. So when they check a box it dumps the layer and reloads it with the right filter.  http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/filter/filter.html 
There maybe a better way by having a Yes layer and a No layer, then just turning the right one on/off but this method met my needs.

Comment: Hei, If I understood you correctly, then that's what's working already also for me. I'd like to combine that with another filter on another parameter

Comment: Sure in the filter expression use && or ||, In the past I've made three different layers from the same GeoJSON file. .

Comment: Ah, ok. i think I got it. But this means I'd need one layer for each possible combination of levels from parameter and and 2, right?

Comment: Yes, it also allows you to use a different symbol for each layer if needed.

Comment: Mhm, I think that’d result in too many layer definitions and makes the whole thing messy. I’d rather want to use something like that:   `function filter(feature, layer) { if (feature.properties.Par1 == “User Input Checkbox 1” && feature.properties.Par2 == “User Input Checkbox 2”) return true; };` The Icon should depend always on Par1