# Multiple on-the-fly filtering based on markers' features on leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I would like to filter the markers on my (geojson) layer according to two features: year and type of event, ideally using both filters (year and eventType) as check-boxes without using layerGroup at all. I would like to be able to click on a checkbox and update dynamically the markers by filtering them according to `feature.properties.eventType` too, *in addition* to the year displayed, something like

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" value="all">
  <label for="all">All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="funfair" name="funfair" value="newsletter">
  <label for="funfair">Funfair</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="trade" name="trade" value="trade">
  <label for="trade">Trade</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="exhibition" name="exhibition" value="exhibition">
  <label for="exhibition">Paid exhibition</label>
```

etc... which would trigger a

```
filter: function(feature, layer) {
  return feature.properties.eventType == value-of-checkbox;
}
```

I have five types of eventType. So, for instance, if 1890 is checked, the map is showing all 1890 events, no matter what kind of event it is (because by default it would show all events). If the user checks the 'funfair' and the 'trade' checkbox, though, I want the map to show only the 1890 events of the funfair and trade kind, and not other kind of events.

This is my complete script, which so far is working fine with filtering by year.

```
var oldmap = L.tileLayer('address', {
  maxZoom: 12
}),

var modernmap = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  maxZoom: 12,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'mytoken'
});

var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [40.1857864,-4.5536861],
  zoom: 7,
  layers: [oldmap, modernmap]
});

var baseMaps = {
  "Old map": oldmap,
  "Modern map": modernmap
};

var jsontest = {"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates":  [ -16.5471268,28.4136726 ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Name":"Point1",
        "year":'1892',
        "eventType":"funfair",
        "notes":""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates":  [ 2.1753895,41.3767925 ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Name":"Point2",
        "year":'1890',
        "eventType":"trade demonstration",
        "notes":""
      }
    }
  ]};

var mapLayerGroupsYear = [];

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  var year = mapLayerGroupsYear[feature.properties.year];
  if (year === undefined) {
    year = new L.layerGroup();

    //add the layer to the map
    year.addTo(map);

    //store layer
    mapLayerGroupsYear[feature.properties.year] = year;
  }

  //add the feature to the layer
  year.addLayer(layer);   
}


var myLayer = L.geoJSON(jsontest, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
})

L.control.layers(baseMaps, mapLayerGroupsYear).addTo(map);
```

I am a beginner with leaflet so please forgive the dumb question, in case it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose to have `<input>` checkboxes for both the years and the event types *outside* the map container. The `filter` function in the `L.GeoJson` definition rejects every feature that does not have both the respective checkboxes for its year and for its event type checked.

```js
const geojsonLayer = L.geoJSON(null,{
    filter: (feature) => {
        const isYearChecked = checkboxStates.years.includes(feature.properties.year)
        const isEventTypeChecked = checkboxStates.eventTypes.includes(feature.properties.eventType)
        return isYearChecked && isEventTypeChecked //only true if both are true
    }
}).addTo(map)
```

Now every time the state of a checkbox changes, all markers are removed, `checkboxStates` is updated and then data is added again, going through the filter.

```js
for (let input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
    //Listen to 'change' event of all inputs
    input.onchange = (e) => {
        geojsonLayer.clearLayers()
        updateCheckboxStates()
        geojsonLayer.addData(jsontest)   
    }
}
```

The utility function `updateCheckboxStates` is here. It assumes that the `<input>` elements have a class of either `event-type` or `year`.

```js
function updateCheckboxStates() {
    checkboxStates = {
        years: [],
        eventTypes: []
    }

    for (let input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
        if(input.checked) {
            switch (input.className) {
                case 'event-type': checkboxStates.eventTypes.push(input.value); break
                case 'year': checkboxStates.years.push(input.value); break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/newluck77/rk9v0uyo/

---

Edit: And three screenshots comparing behaviour:

#### *All events*

[image: All checkboxes ticked]

#### *Trade demonstrations and events of 1892 excluded*

[image: No trade demonstrations and no events of 1892]

#### *Events of 1892 added again (trade demonstrations stay excluded)*

[image: No trade demonstrations]

Comment: Hi @Stefan, thanks so much for replying and the fiddle! I was able to reach a similar result using the filter. My issues begin when I combine the eventType filtering with the year filtering. I can't find the year layering in your code/fiddle. Could you please confirm if/how/ this would work nicely with year filtering as well?

Comment: You have year in your layers control, right? If you uncheck the year there, all markers with that year will disappear.

Comment: Oh and if you have a working solution, post it as answer so that others can learn from it.

Comment: Thanks so much @Stefan, that's definitely getting close. It's still misbehaving, though. For instance, if you go here: https://tinyurl.com/ycju8lqd; deselect all the checkboxes and leave only 'funfair'; deselect all the years; check only one year (say, 1890), you get all the markers from that year, regardless of their eventType. I guess this is because there's no "onchange" check on the year checkboxes, is that correct?

Comment: ...in other words, when one starts 'playing' with the year-checkboxes, my eventType checkboxes get ignored.

Comment: PS: I've updated the fiddle adding all my data and code: https://jsfiddle.net/rk9v0uyo/124/

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for providing the demo. I'll look at it later.

Comment: I thought I could use an array with the currently checked items:

```var eventsChecked = ["funafair", etc];
[...]

if (e.target.checked === true) {

      eventsChecked.push(e.target.value)
      console.log(eventsChecked)}



      else {
        var i = eventsChecked.indexOf(e.target.value);
        if(i != -1) {
        eventsChecked.splice(i, 1);
        console.log(eventsChecked)}
      }```

So that the 'year' checkbox can check if the item is in the array (i.e. is checked) or not. Still, I don't know how to get the 'year' checkboxes to perform this.

Comment: The "year" checkboxes are also `<input>` elements (Right-click > Inspect Element) and they perform the same `onchange` function as our manually added `<input>` elements. However they don't have the `value` set. You should probably ditch the `L.control.layer` completely and define all your checkboxes outside the map container.

Comment: I've actually been able to get the value of the year-checkboxes (`e.srcElement.labels[0].firstChild.textContent`), and also managed to get them into a dynamic array as well. But anyway, either in the controlLayer or not, I still have the issue that one (years) ignores the other (eventType). I've edited the fiddle to include both the arrays.

Comment: I have completely reworked my answer and the jsfiddle. Please have a look at it. :)

Comment: Thanks :) It seems as it was before, with the same issue... if I take the 'years' off and on again, all the markers will be there, regardless of the eventType checked or not. Also, I've now taken the years-selector out of the #map, just for consistency (see https://tinyurl.com/ycju8lqd). Would this make thinks better? Anyway, as I said, the fiddle still doesn't do what I need, unfortunately.

Comment: AS far as I can see the issue is here: `e.target.checked ? c.style.display = 'inherit' : c.style.display = 'none'`: I want to add 'inherit' only if `c.className` contains the eventType or the years which are selected, if any.

Comment: You are using some old code on that website. I refrained from using the display CSS property. Are you sure you looked at the right version of the jsfiddle? -> https://jsfiddle.net/newluck77/rk9v0uyo

Comment: Ah, OK, I've now seen the new fiddle. The problem is that when I implement your code in my website and add the years checkboxes I can't see any marker and the console doesn't give me any error. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I CAN'T BELIEVE IT, IT'S WORKING!!!! :D This is just fantastic, thank you so much. I'll take my time to test it properly tomorrow. You rock!